# Automatic iCloud backup without locking iPad

Tags: ipad, ios, backup, icloud

When enabled, iCloud will automatically back up your iOS device when it is plugged in, connected to Wi-Fi, and locked. This is designed so it'll very conveniently back up overnight. However, I use a night stand app, and I have it set to prevent my iPad from sleeping so I can see what time it is without having to fumble around with a passcode in the middle of the night. Because of this, iCloud will never back up automatically.

Is there any way I can get it to *automatically* back up without requiring my iPad to be locked? I have no wish to jailbreak it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately not. According to [this knowledgebase article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1766), Apple has it set up to only automatically back up when it's connected to Wi-Fi, connected to a power source and (unfortunately for you) the screen is locked.

You *can*, however, get in the habit of doing a backup before you go to sleep, kind of like setting your alarm clock. Just a suggestion, but I think this is the only way to make it happen daily without jailbreaking (truth be told, I don't know of a way to do this even if you did jailbreak).

Good luck.

Comment: Oh, well, I guss that's the most viable option. Thanks!